# laravel 8 jetstream logout

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream, laravel-authentication

I m using Laravel 8 - Jetstream for Authentification and i set a session variable : `session(['isAdmin'=>'true'])` on login :

```
//app\Providers\JetstreamServiceProvider.php

...

public function boot()
{
  ...
    
  Fortify::authenticateUsing(function(LoginRequest $request){
  ...
  //verifications
  session(['isAdmin'=>'true'])
  ...

}
```

If The user Logs out in Jetstream *(using `POST` request to `/logout`)* the `session('isAdmin')` is `null`.
The problem is what if the user **didn't Log out** but the session expired , because then the `session('isAdmin')`  will be `null` but the user is still logged in (he didn't use the *`POST` request to `/logout`* ) .
I can't test this because i don't know if the session variables expire or no in Laravel maybe it's using database for sessions … 
Any informations on how does the Laravel session works with the Authentification system in Jetstream ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on `/logout` the user gets logged out from the Application and user session reset and hence all session data destroy. like in your case `session('isAdmin')` is set to `null`.

In case of session expire and user is not logged out using `post` request to `/logout`, then the session will also reset on next request(post session expire). In this case user will be logged out(as session expired) and session data will be destroyed. This works in same way for file and database driver for session.

Comment: Can you please add some documentation. Thank you so much